# Create array of tf objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If I wanted to create an array of specified class I would use an approach like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html). So creating an array of `int` looks like this:

```
Aint = int16.empty(5,0);
Aint(1) = 3;
```

And it works fine. Now I want to create an array of `tf` class objects. My approach was similar:

```
L = tf.empty(5, 0);
s = tf('s');
L(1) = s;
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error using InputOutputModel/subsasgn (line 57)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in tf_array (line 6)
L(1) = s;
```

I also made sure to display `class(s)` and it correctly says it's `tf`. **What do I do wrong here?**

Comment: From the documentation you linked: "You can use `empty` with any MATLAB _fundamental_ type or class". `tf` belongs to a toolbox, so it probably doesn't qualify as fundamental

Comment: @LuisMendo oh God, is there a way to create an array of tf then?

Comment: I never used `tf` nor do I have that toolbox, sorry

Comment: I don't have those toolboxes either, but can you initialize the array without being empty?

Comment: @Wick what I want to do is set each element of the array in a `for` loop (eg. `L(i) = s^i`)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that object, but usually you can do that without initialization. MATLAB complains that it's not fast because it has to reallocate memory on the fly. But perhaps it's worth it? Certainly you can extend a vector of structures without warning MATLAB ahead of time. Rather than calling `L = tf.empty` just define s in your loop and assign `L(ii) = s;` Maybe.

Comment: Also, why initialize empty? If you know you're going to overwrite your assignment, just initialize at (5,1) instead of (5,0). Again, hard to say without knowing the properties of that object.

Comment: You can just use a cell array, which can store any class of objects in each element, indexed with curly braces `{}` and initialised with `cell(n,m)` for `n` rows and `m` columns

Comment: `L = tf.empty(5, 0)` gives an error but if you put a semi-colon at the end (as in the question) then it executes. I don't get it

Comment: @SardarUsama: Probable explanation: Creating the empty array is OK, but displaying it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html#mw_390073dc-1174-4dd6-bd37-243f68c53f40) has an example for how to do this sort of thing:

> ```
>  sys = tf(zeros(1,1,3));
>  s = tf('s');                                                  
>  for k = 1:3                                                             
>    sys(:,:,k) = k/(s^2+s+k);                                          
>  end
> ```

So, the problem likely is that the indexing `L(1)` is wrong, it needs to be `L(:,:,1)`.

Do note that `tf.empty(5, 0)` is instructing to create a 5x0 array (i.e. an empty array). There is no point to this. You might as well just skip this instruction. Because when you later do `L(:,:,1)`, you'll be increasing the array size any way (it starts with 0 elements, you want to assign a new element, it needs to reallocate the array). You should always strive to create the arrays of the right size from the start.